# Getting TCP RST packet when try to create connection

Tags: c#, tcp, pcap.net

I am trying to create tcp connection.

I am sending tcp SYN and getting SYN-ACK.
 Afterwards, I am sending ACK message.

However, before my last ACK is sending I am getting RST reset packet. I can see that using wireshark sniffer.

I am writing my code in C# , an using pcap .NET library, over Win7.

How can I fix the problem and what makes it happen?

Comment: A pcap file with the packets would be helpful to understand what's going on. It might be bad ports or maybe you take too long with the next packet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that your OS receives a SYN/ACK that it cannot associate on a source port and thus the OS TCP/IP stack sends a RST.

What do you exactly want to do? You could suppress the RST with a local firewall.

Comment: I am trying to create the "three way handshake" in pcapDotNet.